# Is testing whether the nonunits of $K[x,y]_{(x,y)}[1/y]$ form an ideal a messy undertaking or am I going about it wrong?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, localization

I'm studying the ideals of $R = K[x,y]_{(x,y)}[1/y]$: the polynomials in $1/y$ with coefficients in the localization of $K[x,y]$ at the ideal $(x,y)$. I've managed to identify that its units are given by members $h_1/h_2 \in R$ who have their numerator $h_1$ in $\langle y \rangle (K[x,y] - {(x,y)}) $, understood as the set of nonnegative powers of $y$ multiplied by an element in $K[x,y]$ that is not in $(x,y)$, so now I'm trying to figure out if the nonunits, given by $$I_? = \{h_1/h_2 \in K[x,y]_{(x,y)}[1/y]: h_1 \notin \langle y \rangle (K[x,y] -{(x,y)}) \}$$ form an ideal, and I'm working on a proof that involves proving closure under substraction, since nonunits are multiplicatively closed, but laboriously expanding and carefully arguing about the form of the resulting polynomials is starting to get messy. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Why is this a thing you need to do?

Comment: @HankScorpio I'd like to see whether we can choose a specific element to extend nonvaluation local rings into valuation rings, so I'm trying out how extension by an element behaves

Comment: Aren't $x$ and $y-x$ non-invertible?

Comment: @user26857 indeed! those are not in $\langle y \rangle (K[x,y] \setminus (x,y))$, understood as the set of nonnegative powers of $y$ multiplied by an element in $K[x,y]$: both $x$ and $y-x$ are in $(x,y)$, and are therefore in $y^0(x,y)$ and so not in $\langle y \rangle (K[x,y] \setminus (x,y))$, making them nonunits.

Comment: I'm sorry because the problem is difficult to parse as I have written it so if someone has a suggestion on a clearer notation, or way to present it, I would also appreciate it

Comment: Problem solved: the ring R is not local since the sum of two non-units is an unit.

Comment: oh! I understand now! elegant solution thank you. If you would post this as an answer I would award you the bounty, if you'd like, but in any case, thank you very much!